# show in app review when user open for 2 time ? Please any one share the code for this

Tags: java, android, review

I want to show the review after the user open my app for the second time. Can anyone share the code for this.

Thanks in advaNCE.........

```
ReviewManager manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(this);
Task<ReviewInfo> request = manager.requestReviewFlow();
request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        // We can get the ReviewInfo object
        ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();
    } else {
        // There was some problem, log or handle the error code.
        @ReviewErrorCode int reviewErrorCode = ((TaskException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();
    }
});
```

..............

Comment: What's the problem? Are you having problems using this Review API? Or are you looking for a way to implement it?

Comment: Im looking to implement this feature , i want to show the review , when the user open my app for the second time or after certain amount of time..Im new as java developer. I want the code for that feature. Kindly share the code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you need to store the user open app count in the database or etc, I suggest you use [SharedPrefrence](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore), which are both of them based on the key-value collection.
Well in the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("app_setting", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int openCount = preferences.getInt("app_open_count", 0);
    if (openCount >= 2) {
        // show the review manager dialog
    } else {
        preferences.edit().putInt("app_open_count", ++openCount).apply();
    }
}
```

}

Also, you can increase the *app_open_count* in *SplashActivity* or wherever you want. I did it at MainActivity because MainActivity is my application's first activity the user has seen. this is not complex code and you can modify that.